# How to fix **Lost sync to device** error when running rosrun?

Tags: c++, ros, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I am learning the ROS operating system with an ESP32 module, I started with an example found in Arduino "ros_lib", specifically "Blink", which gives me the code below:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#define LED_BUILTIN 2

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void messageCb( const std_msgs::Empty& toggle_msg){
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH-digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));   // blink the led
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Empty> sub("Led_conmutador", &messageCb );

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{  
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

I proceed to load the code to the ESP32 and then run the command **rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py** but I get this error:

[image]

I have done some research and it points to the **sipnOnce** function not being called frequently but I really don't know what the real problem is, whether it is my ESP32 or the arduino IDE let alone how to fix it, if someone could tell me what the problem is and how to fix it I would really appreciate it.